# Shapefile projections not matching up in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

To start off with, I'm very new to QGIS. I'm attempting to place a shapefile with locations for 3 substations on a map of Peniche, Portugal. The locations for the substations are given in latitude and longitude coordinates.

When I start off by importing the substation shapefile, I make sure that both the layer CRS and project CRS are set to EPSG:32629, which gives each substation point the correct coordinates, however the scale is at 1:1, which is not correct. As soon as I then add a raster map of the region or a shapefile of Portugal using the same CRS the position of the substations also becomes incorrect.

I'm sure there's a simple solution I'm not getting, but I've been trying for a while and have had no success. Here's a dropbox link to the files
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/53kcszzry8kekqx/AADsHaKMpkiCzmNWjSPapC1Ma?dl=0

Answer (score 6):

If the substation coordinates are given in latitude and longitude, the CRS can not be EPSG:32629. EPSG:4326 seems more reasonable, or a local datum with degrees as units.

You should not use `Set Layer CRS` to cahnge the CRS, but `save As ...` to a different name and CRS.

You can install openstreetmap background with the OpenLayers plugin to see if the stations are placed correctly.

The border shapefile seems to be correct with UTM 29N. To share the files, you need to add the .shx file as well.